# Is PostgreSQL (14.1) able to tell me how much RAM it is currently using?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I'm trying to keep track of how much RAM PostgreSQL is using. I need to do this with a SQL query -- not relying on the always incompatible and finicky OS tools.

Is there a way to get the currently used RAM (not disk storage) in bytes used by PostgreSQL at the moment? Possibly even per-database?

I found nothing but nonsensical articles and discussions when I researched this prior to asking.

Comment: This is a rather old blog post but probably the best info on the Internet about [How much RAM is PostgreSQL using?](https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/09/how-much-ram-is-postgresql-using/)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could consider monitoring frameworks that measure both PG and OS simultaneously. [PGmonitor](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pgmonitor) from crunchydata or Perconsa's [PMM tool](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management).   There are generic frameworks (Nagios/Zabbix), but I'd go with the specialists...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

You can query the size of `shared_buffers`, but there is no central accounting for the amount of private memory that the individual backends have allocated. Moreover, PostgreSQL makes use of the “unused” memory in the machine by virtue of the kernel cache, so any accounting of the above would be inaccurate.